# Change Header Key for rest_framework's TokenAuthorization

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

By default, rest_framework's TokenAuthentication uses the "Authorization" key in the header, and looks for the keyword "Token" when authenticating requests.

```
Authorization: Token [value]
```

How do I change it to use the "API-AUTH" key instead, and no keyword?

```
API-AUTH: [value]
```

Comment: As far as I know Token will be compulsory there. It is a default syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a custom permission class that extends from `TokenAuthentication` and overrides the `.authenticate()` method.

The following codes are the modified code of the `TokenAuthentication.authenticate()` that accepts a request with `API-AUTH` as auth header name with the value of token with no keyword. You can find the original source code in the GitHub of Django rest framework [here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/authentication.py#L177:L196).

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

from rest_framework import authentication
from rest_framework import exceptions
from rest_framework import HTTP_HEADER_ENCODING


class CustomTokenAuthentication(authentication.TokenAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        auth = request.META.get('HTTP_API_AUTH', b'')
        if isinstance(auth, str):
            # Work around django test client oddness
            auth = auth.encode(HTTP_HEADER_ENCODING)

        auth = auth.split()
        if not auth:
            return None
        elif len(auth) > 1:
            msg = _('Invalid token header. Token string should not contain spaces.')
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(msg)

        try:
            token = auth[0].decode()
        except UnicodeError:
            msg = _('Invalid token header. Token string should not contain invalid characters.')
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(msg)

        return self.authenticate_credentials(token)
```

Then you can add `CustomTokenAuthentication` into settings.

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        ...  # other permission classes
        'path.to.CustomTokenAuthentication',
    ),
    ...  # other settings
}
```

**Notes**

- Further readings about custom authentication can be found [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#custom-authentication).